# Force hdmi audio output

Tags: debian

Quick question i have a rp4 project that sends video and audio through HDMI on tv.
late at night i turn off the TV and go to sleep the next morning the raspberry reboots at 7:15 everyday and starts playing music and video but at that time i'm not awake yet which means the TV is not turned on yet,which means the rp4 can't find the HDMI output (if I'm not mistaken) if i then turn on the TV there is no audio.

to fix this issue i had to go into:
/boot/config.txt and enable the line hdmi_drive=2

is there anyway i could do that on a Debian desktop PC as well? i can't find any information on that

Comment: I think you need to set hdmi_group and hdmi_mode to force the required resolution https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Answer (score 2):

The Raspberry Pi has a proprietary boot loader, configurable with `/boot/config.txt`. You will not find similar on any other computer. Debian by default uses **grub** as boot loader. How to set audio out to HDMI is out of scope on Raspberry Pi. Look at the documentation to HDMI and/or grub on your desktop PC how to do it.

Comment: thanks for the help unfortunately i have not fixed it yet. but luckily that was not the problem it's something else that's bugging. i can't figure out what it is